# WordPress custom theme live preview and customization is not saving current preview

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am developing a website with Wordpress. I am using gt3themes' corp theme. I have managed to customize layout of my site, but when it comes to partners and/or featured posts sections, theme's javascript is not working as expected. You can see the preview of [the site](http://dev.hsb.uz). I have tried to deactivate the all of my active plugins, but it still not working. However, when i live preview my theme, it is showing the layout as expected, but when i save and publish it, it is becoming as before.

Before activation

[image: This is before activation of the theme]

After activation

[image: This is after activation of the theme]

As you can see here, in the first image, it is a live preview and, for example, Our partners section is showing only 5 partners and the rest of them are hidden. Whereas, in the second image, all partners in this section is visible, just overflow made hidden.
The same problem with Latest News and Announcements section.

I have reviewed javascript files, and cannot differentiate from theme's live demo which you can find [here](http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/corp/).

Any suggessions that can solve my problem would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: We're not digging through all that and manually comparing the code for you.  Once you isolate the issue to a particular portion and **post the relevant code**, then we can help.  Also, try resolving the errors reported by your browser console.

Answer (score 0):

I´m actually not really sure how we would be able to really help you without the files of the theme. Altough i just had a quick overlook between your website and the theme preview at http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/corp/, and it seems to me you have a problem with the carousel control, that is on the right side of the partner section in the preview.

also you have more js loaded than their preview.

Looks like a typical failure of some javascript not loaded right or not loaded at all.

Also you are loading two times the jquery library in different versions, one in the header, one in the footer. Try to solve this issues.